# slow down button animation swift

Tags: swift, animation, uibutton

I have a button in a table view cell. On click I am starting a download task and want to start animating the button images with 4 images only.

Then when the download delegate triggers didComplete, I am reloading my tableview which will stop the animation.

I need to slow down this animation so the transition between each image isn't so fast. But I haven't been able to manage it. 
Code below:

```
btn.imageView!.animationImages = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "unsubscribed2"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "subbing1"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "subbing2"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "subscribed3")]
            btn.imageView!.startAnimating()
```

I also tried:

```
for i in 0...arrItems.count - 1 {
                UIView.transition(with: btn, duration: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                    btn.setImage(arrItems[i], for: .normal)
                }, completion: nil)
        }
```

Where arrItems is an array of my 4 images. But that didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
btn.imageView!.animationDuration = TimeInterval(Seconds)
```

where seconds are the total time that takes to the cycle to complete, so for example if you want it to last 10 secons you'd use:

```
TimeInterval(10)
```

but if you want each image to last 3 seconds you could do:

```
TimeInterval(imagesArrayCount * 3)
```